# Custom context processor doesn't work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I have the following code:

1) context processor

```
def defaults(request):
    return {
        'LOGO_DEFAULT_SRC': LOGO_DEFAULT_CSRC
    }
```

2) settings

```
  'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # custom processors
                'apps.core.context_processors.defaults',
            ],
```

3) in template

```
{{ defaults.LOGO_DEFAULT_SRC }}
```

4) I use Generic Class Based View.

I don't understand why this isn't working. I restarted the server, cleaned .pyc files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a context processor, the dictionary that you return in the `defaults` function is added to the global context, so you can access this in your template just by its name.

Instead of using:

```
{{ defaults.LOGO_DEFAULT_SRC }}
```

you need to use:

```
{{LOGO_DEFAULT_SRC}}
```